# Store an object tree to csv/xlsx

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an object like this one:

```
{
    "Group1": {
        "Category1": "Value1 | Value2 | Value3",
        "Category2": "Value1 | Value2 | Value3"
    },
    "Group2": {
        "Category3": "Value1 | Value2 | Value3",
        "Category4": "Value1 | Value2 | Value3"
    }
}
```

What I am trying to get should look like that:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbhDa.jpg)

It doesn't matter if it's CSV or XLSX, I tried to use some packages from npm to convert json -> csv / xlsx , got some result, but not the one I'm looking for.

Until now, my only idea was getting an array like on my second sreenshot and then converting it to CSV using some special package from npm:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idZHo.png)

But maybe there is some solution which is more simple?
Any help will be appreciated a lot! Peace!

Comment: please add the wanted result, at least the last in text form to the question. btw, what have you tried?

Comment: the wanted result is .csv or .xlsx file like on the first screenshot. Well, I'll add what I've tried to the post in a few minutes

Comment: Or could you please give me a hint how to get an array like on my second screenshot from that object? I tried to do it, but got too complicated and have literally no ideas about it

Comment: @DennisCasteel Welcome to SO! Typically with these questions you should provide what code you have already tried to achieve your desired result

Comment: @acupajoe will do, give me some time please

Comment: Similar solution, but more procedural: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/eadws7m2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an approach by changing the object to an object with an empty key and map all nested properties with a space in the result set

Basically it takes the entries of the object and looks for other object and if so, it calls the function again or take the key and value for a new row in the result set.

Each recursive result set is padded with an empty space in the row and for all nested properties, you get an according indention.

```js
function getCSV(object) {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        if (v && typeof v === 'object') {
            if (k) r.push([k]);
            r.push(...getCSV(v).map(a => ['', ...a]));
        } else {
            r.push([k, v]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var data = { Group1: { Category1: "Value1 | Value2 | Value3", Category2: "Value1 | Value2 | Value3" }, Group2: { Category3: "Value1 | Value2 | Value3", Category4: "Value1 | Value2 | Value3" } },
    result = getCSV({ '': data });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or take a spacer array for the wanted empty strings.

```js
function getCSV(object, length = 0) {
    var spacer = Array.from({ length }, _ => '');
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        if (v && typeof v === 'object') {
            r.push(spacer.concat(k));
            r.push(...getCSV(v, length + 1));
        } else {
            r.push(spacer.concat([k, v]));
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var data = { Group1: { Category1: "Value1 | Value2 | Value3", Category2: "Value1 | Value2 | Value3" }, Group2: { Category3: "Value1 | Value2 | Value3", Category4: "Value1 | Value2 | Value3" } },
    result = getCSV(data, 1);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Could you please add some comments to your code? I mean I'm very curious about what does your code do.. For example that function argument "length = 0". It seems like something alien for me, I've never seen anything like that before as a function argument. Or maybe you can tell me what should I read about (some JS tutorial chapter) to understand every string of your code